# Trocar ponto por virgula e adicionar ponto

Tags: php, formatação, replace, number-format

Como faço para adicionar a virgula na casa decimal e o ponto nos milhares.

Exemplo:

```
$pagamento = R$ 1000.50;

/* trecho a fazer a operação */

echo $pagamento; //saída: "R$ 1.000,50"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a função [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php) para a sua alteração

```
$valor = 1000.50;
$valor = number_format($valor, 2 , ",", ".");
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara

```
$moeda = 'R$ 1.550,52';

$valor = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $moeda);    
$valor = bcdiv($valor, 100, 2);
$valor = strtr($valor, '.', ',');

echo $valor;
```

Ou se quiser separado por `.`

```
$moeda = 'R$ 1.550,52';

$valor = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $moeda);    
$valor = bcdiv($valor, 100, 2);
$valor = strtr($valor, ',', '.');

echo $valor;
```

Comment: "Virgula e ponto"

Comment: real, ajustei aqui pra se adequar melhor ao que o jovem precisava.

Comment: optei por o mais simples para nao aumentar as linhas do meu codigo na minha tabela

Comment: A questão é que se vc garantir que o valor de `$moeda` sempre será numerico, beleza! Se não, esse codigo acima vai te ajudar!